# What is the risk of giving a 3rd party read only access to Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console, security

An agency has asked for access to my Google Analytics.   I don't really trust them, but I need them to be able to verify my web site stats.  What are the risks associated with giving them read only access to Google Analytics?

For example, can they use that access to get Google Search Console access to my site?  I know there are settings in search console that I wouldn't trust them to mess with.

Answer (score 2):

Read access is limited and they can only see the data you are providing to them, nothing else. In order to access or connect other Google Platforms an admin account is always needed.

Don't worry, [read access is secure](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2884495?hl=en).